# How to find main method of dynamic web project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a dynamic web project in eclipse. Now I have a situation in which I need to start a thread while application gets started[Short of in main method].
Now I searched the whole project for the class containing the main method. But I didn't get it.

Like in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now I want to execute some code before index.jsp gets loaded..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: if you are not using embeded webserver then main method would be from your external webserver, google for "eclipse dynamic web project tutorial"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general web applications are started from the application container and thus do not need to have a main method.

You may want to add a [context listner](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) so that you get notifyed about the start of the web application and where you can start your thread.

[Here you can find an example.](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/)

Comment: This seems to be helpful to me.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can set a servlet load on start up, means it will run on the start up on the server like Apache tomcat..

But make sure the task that you are going to performs should be in thread as until the execution of task that you have written in load on start up servlet will not finish web server will not up and running, so if your task will take time than web server will say it cannot start in xyz seconds and web server will not up.

to make a server load on start up you need to configure it in web.xml

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>initServelet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.initServelet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

and in your servlet you need to implement init  method this method will be called on start up of server.

```
 public class initServelet extends HttpServlet {
   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
     // your code goes here
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Web applications do not have a main method.

Instead you should initialize your application in one of the Lifecycle events. Take a look at this  [example](http://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2009/07/create-application-lifecycle-listener.htmlhttp://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2009/07/create-application-lifecycle-listener.html)

Comment: It can have main method if you are using embedded server

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Filter which intercepts call to your index.jsp and perform any init operations.

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm

Comment: Filter is not the best idea, as it will get executed every time the index.jsp is requested